# WooCommerce: Get a shareable link of multiple product attribute values

Tags: woocommerce

Here is a product attribute (public)

```
Age
```

And following were the configured values with their slugs

```
    1-2 Years (1-2-years)
    2-4 Years (2-4-years)
    4-6 Years (4-6-years)
```

And we could use combine all three together to have it's own archive page.

For example:
https://www.example.com/age/1-2-years,2-4-years,4-6-years/

Here the attribute values are separated using a comma

I guess it used to work earlier but now it only considers first value to show products, in this case 1-2-years.

Any ideas how we can use multiple attribute values together?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, as WordPress taxonomy (or custom taxonomy) archives pages are based on a unique term. What you could do instead, is to use query string parameters that will filter products from a tax_query from shop page.

Answer (score 0):

> Here the attribute values are separated using a comma
> I guess it used to work earlier but now it only considers first value to show products, in this case 1-2-years.

Just to confirm, you want the link to have all the attributes preselected, correct

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
https://example.com/product/test-var-product/?attribute_pa_{name}={term}
```

For example:

```
https://example.com/product/test-var-product/?attribute_pa_vape-flavour=juice-apple
```

You can find the values in the DOM. I've highlighted them in this screenshot:

[image: You can find the values in the DOM (I've highlighted them in this screenshot).]

Another example with two attributes:

```
https://example.com/product/test-var-product/?attribute_pa_vape-flavour=juice-apple&attribute_brand=vape-brand-example
```